# highcharts tooltip stop update when mouse over

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

In a highcharts line chart, I want to present a link in the tooltip for people to explore the underlying data set for a specific point by clicking on it (done, I used useHTML). The chart itself is an aggregated view showing statistics for some values (y) for different categories (series) across time scale (x), hence the motivation for exploring the non-aggregated data.

However, when the chart becomes dense enough, the user cannot mouseover the tooltip to click the link because it updates with the adjacent data points from the next point/s. Thus, I want to stop the tooltip from updating when the mouse is directly on top of it. How am I able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play around with [`tooltip.positioner`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.positioner) - to make sure user will be able to click that tooltip URL. Or just change logic, so user can click on column instead, just like demo [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click).

Comment: positioner looks like too much trouble, maybe i'll just add click on column. Thanks!